# Is online storage a practical solution?

Tags: online-storage

I am trying to purchase an online storage and there are lot of them Apple, Google, Amazon, DropBox etc etc but I am worried is it really practical because of slow transfer speeds esp the upload speed.

My question is, Is online storage solution practical for lets say 200 GB of photos and Mp3 where photos size can be as large as 25 MB. How about if I have some small video clips.

I know it is practical for document but my question is related to this big high def photos + mp3 + a lot of documents.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean 200 **GB**? 200 MB isn't very much at all and should upload rather quickly even if your upload speed is only average.

Comment: @bdr9 fixed.My data may actually be more than 200 GB but it is a reasonable size for me. Yes it is not 200 MB :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a relatively slow ADSL Internet connection (supposedly 1.5 M down and 896K up) and have found it practical to use such services because most of them are smart and only upload changes. The initial upload *can* take a long time, but the process is interruptible allowing it to be resumed at later time, and generally only has to be done once.